# Stuck on Double Integral $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \int_{0}^{u} \frac{1}{1- \frac{u^2 - v^2}{2}} dv du $

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, trigonometric-integrals

I was stuck on this double integral below and wondered if anyone could help me out on it.

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \int_{0}^{u} \frac{1}{1- \frac{u^2 - v^2}{2}} dv du $$

I know it needs to be in arctan integration form; however, I am stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Treat the $v^2$ as a constant and integrate wrt $u$ to start with. Multiply top & bottom by $2$ and notice your integrand is in the form $k \times \frac 1 {a^2 - u^2}$.

Comment: @PrimeMover Thank you for helping. To clarify, are you saying to switch the limits of integration at the beginning? Thanks again :)

Comment: The way it's written, you first integrate $dv$ which means $u$ is constant. Otherwise ($v$ is constant) requires not only swithching limits, but redefining them because they are NOT independant.

Comment: @Amber Oh yes of course, keep $u$ constant and integrate wrt $v$, what was I talking about. You will end up with an integral of the form $k \times \frac 1 {v^2 + a^2}$. But then you worked that out by yourself because you're smart. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as follows

\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \int_{0}^{u} \frac{1}{1- \frac{u^2 - v^2}{2}} dv \>du \\
=& \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \int_{0}^{u} \frac{2}{2- u^2 + v^2} dv \>du 
 =\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2- u^2}} \arctan\frac u{\sqrt{2-u^2} }\>du \\
 =& \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2- u^2}} \arcsin\frac u{\sqrt2 }\>du 
=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}/2} d\left(\arcsin^2\frac u{\sqrt2}\right)
=\frac{\pi^2}{36}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful :)